# Google Apps SAML SSO and apps that support google login

Tags: single-sign-on, google-apps, saml

If I build a trust with a an Identity Provider and Google Apps using SAML, I can SSO into Google Apps.  If I have a session with Google Apps, I can then navigate to a website that supports a Google login (has a sign in with google button such as the one in the screenshot below), is there a way to direct the authentication to go through a SSO flow. I still need to click the "Sign in with Google" button but since I have a session with google apps it goes through the SSO flow and logs me in to the app.

If I'm not signed into Google Apps, I have to not only click the button, but then I have to enter my email address.  This will initiate SSO since email address (domain) is federated, but it's too many steps.

[image]

In the case of apps like Google Drive, you can use a URL like https://drive.google.com/a/ to initiate an SSO type flow.  I'm wondering if there is a similar paradigm or a process that can be used to do something for a 3rd party website that supports Google Login.

Thanks.